# d3 add multiple classes with function

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have the svg as:

```
<g class="user" title="Michael" rel="tooltip" transform = "rotate(-12.364052661705784)translate(360)" style="fill: #9467bd; "></g>
```

I want to add a class as the same as title. I tried

```
d3.selectAll('.user').attr('class','Michael');
```

But it replaced the original class. Then I tried

```
d3.selectAll('.user').classed('Michael',true);
```

It works! But now I want to return the class name with a function like

```
d3.selectAll('.user').classed(function(){return this.attr('title');},true);
```

It doesn't work. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can assign multiple classes to elements by simply separating their names with spaces:

```
d3.selectAll(".user").attr("class", "user Michael");
```

But it seems that what you really need is to assign a data property to your elements for which it is much better to use the [HTML5 data- attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/). So you could do:

```
d3.selectAll(".user").attr("data-name", function(d,i) { return "Michael #" + i; });
```

and later to obtain the name of a user:

```
d3.select(".user").attr("data-name")
```

Comment: btw, you can also assign multiple classes with `.classed('user Michael', true)`: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections

Answer (score 10):

why use HTML5 data attributes, duplicating data that is already there in the title attribute? HTML5 data attributes sure are useful, but duplicating data is not a good thing.

There is an easy of doing it without data duplication, being close to what you had in mind originally.

```
d3.selectAll('.user').each(
    function(){
        var elt = d3.select(this);
        elt.classed(elt.attr("title"), true);
    }
)
```

Comment: This seems to be a better answer because it actually lets you use a function to set the class which is what was asked for.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to add a class, you can jump out of d3 and use the class list:

```
d3.selectAll('.user').node().classList.add("mynewclass");
```

Might not work in very old browsers tho.

Answer (score 1):

Ilya's answer is good, but if you want to stay inside of the `d3.select().classed()` box the best way to add a class from data is to use the `attr` to add a class:

```
.attr('class', function (d) { return d.class })
```

However that will replace the class with that class, so if you want to add multiple classes then you have to do it in one line.

```
.attr('class', function (d) { return d.class + " " + d.otherclass})
```

This is limited as you can't really *append* classes, but I believe it also solves OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain calls to `classed` using D3.

It is a bit repetitive, but you could do something like:

```
const userCls = 'user'

d3.selectAll(`.${userCls}`)
      .classed(userCls  , true);
      .classed('Michael', true);
```

From my tests using `d3 7.6.1` the second call to classed does not override the class set by the first call.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the selection elements directly in an `.each()` call.

```js
d3.selectAll('.user').each(function (datum, index, groups) {
    var element = groups[index];
    var title = element.getAttribute('title');
    if (title) element.classList.add(title);
});
```

or maybe something from the datum is more useful

```js
d3.selectAll('.user').each(function (datum, index, groups) {
    var element = groups[index];
    if (datum.data.className) 
        element.classList.add(datum.data.className);
});
```